# Wordpress - overridding theme CSS stylesheets

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I'm using Wordpress html5blank theme for the first time. I've deleted everything from the style.css file and copied across my styling and skeleton grid. I've left the normalize.css files alone. 
I'm getting most of my styles applying but not all and can't figure out why this would be the case. By way of an example, this is the top of my Home page using my own front-end files -

[image: Front-end version]

And this is the Wordpress version -

[image: Wordpress version]

How do I ensure that my custom CSS styling is applied all the time and in every circumstance? 
I've researched the child/parent theme but my understanding is that isn't/shouldn't be an issue for this theme as its pretty much an empty shell.

I have this code in the Head of my header.php file -

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/style.css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:100,200,400,700,700i,800,800i' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <script>
        // conditionizr.com
        // configure environment tests
        conditionizr.config({
            assets: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>',
            tests: {}
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!--- header code --->
```

I've looked in the developer tools and the body_class seems to have a number of styles applying - can this be removed?

This is what's in the functions.php file for styles but I'm not sure what I've added is having any effect.

**functions.php**

```
// Load HTML5 Blank styles
function html5blank_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!
}

// MW stylesheets
function load_styles() 
{
    wp_register_style('styles', '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('styles', '/style.css'); // Enqueue it!
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
}
```

And this is what I have at the top of my CSS file -

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: html5blank-stable
Description: HTML5 Blank theme
Template: html5blank-stable
Author: MikeWhitehead00
*/
```

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` will get stylesheet from the parent theme, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will get from the child theme

Comment: @Morpheus So what are you saying? I need to take out all references to template directory in the head?

Comment: no. What I am trying to say is that you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` if you want to override the parent theme styles.

Comment: @Morpheus Sorry, what I meant was, do I replace all references to template with stylesheet in the head? Is that where the crux of the issue lies?

Comment: It depends. Is `html5blank` theme your parent theme? Do you need to override anything in it? If no, leave it as is. If yes, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` within your theme to override `style.css` within the parent theme.

Comment: @Morpheus That hasn't changed anything. It's inheriting from the body_class - I need to override this. Can it simply be removed?

Comment: You can remove it, though not sure about the side implications you may have afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way to include a CSS inside your child-theme.

Copy and paste this function in top of your function.php

```
function override_css(){
     wp_enqueue_style('custom_css_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'override_css');
```

Comment: What does custom_css_name mean? I haven't added a custom name